# Failed to execute goal on project nfctools-examples

Tags: java, maven, nfc

I need to implement nftools library, but is the first time that I work with maven and when I execute a demo I get this error message:

> > Failed to execute goal on project nfctools-examples: Could not resolve dependencies for project
> >     org.nfctools:nfctools-examples:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: The following
> >     artifacts could not be resolved:
> >     org.nfctools:nfctools-api:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT,
> >     org.nfctools:nfctools-core:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT,
> >     org.nfctools:nfctools-ndef:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact
> >     org.nfctools:nfctools-api:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]
>
> To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e
>   switch. Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
>
> For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please
>   read the following articles: [Help 1]
>   http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException

Edited: yes here is my pom.xml file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>NFCTEST</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.nfctools</groupId>
            <artifactId>nfctools-ndef</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.M8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.nfctools</groupId>
            <artifactId>nfctools-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.M8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.nfctools</groupId>
            <artifactId>nfctools-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.M8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.nfctools</groupId>
            <artifactId>nfctools-examples</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Comment: could you paste the code for your pom config for the dependency

Answer (score 0):

Your project `pom` should consist of these for the dependencies you require :

```
<dependencies >
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.nfctools</groupId>
        <artifactId>nfctools-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-M8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.nfctools</groupId>
        <artifactId>nfctools-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.M8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.nfctools</groupId>
        <artifactId>nfctools-ndef</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.M8</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Since examples are not something to be dependent on and doesn't provide any library support, the **rest should be omitted**. 
Still if you require the example package from source, you better know the correct version (if) provided online. Try this if it helps :

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.nfctools</groupId>
  <artifactId>nfctools-examples</artifactId
  <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I have pasted the pom file, but the dependencies are there, what can be wromg?

Comment: @ZanackSayks : edited,don't add examples to dependencies, not requried.